# Timeline on not migrated posts is broken for meta

Tags: bug, mso-mse-split

On meta the timeline url for posts is borked for posts that are not migrated from mse.

`http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/36303/timeline`

returns a 404
where

`http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36303`

does a redirect to

`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303`

Can the url rewrite be extended so it also handles the `posts/{id}/timeline` urls?

Although that link is not public it is used in some posts like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeline feature is (no longer) publicly available; you can access the URL still and user scripts exist that add it back into the UI, but it is considered outdated and unmaintained at the moment. As such I don't care much about links to it being broken.

That said, a [search for the urls](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2Fposts%2F%2A%2Ftimeline) on MSE showed there were only 57 of them. Apart from the massive [2010 recent changes post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/99024#99024) these were easy enough to fix.

Between rene and me we fixed those links in minutes, no need to do anything else about these, really.